# Why debug program of subfolder doesn't appear in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug in vscode, but faced one problem which is the debug programs I previously set in launch.json doesn't appear.
I also found that the vscode shows debug programs from launch.json (the toppest folder, not subfolder)... Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is your `launch.json` included .gitignore? and you somehow pull your code from remote in another directory or another machine?

Comment: yes it has .gitignore. I didn't pull my code from remote.

Comment: adding to .gitignore means this file will not be considered by git and it will not to pushed to remote repository. But if you don't pull your code in another place, then may be your code is accidentally deleted somehow.

Comment: oh, I mistyped. I pulled codes before from remote using git clone.

Comment: ok, so what was wrong? .gitignore doesn't matter when I checked the contents.